# Module not found error while deploying to heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I tried to deploy the my react app to **heroku** but continuously getting this issue while deployment please any can help solve me this issue.[image: screen shot]

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "todo_task",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "ansi-regex": "^3.0.0",
    "antd": "^3.2.3",
    "anymatch": "^2.0.0",
    "async-each": "^1.0.1",
    "chalk": "^2.3.2",
    "chokidar": "^2.0.2",
    "expand-range": "^2.0.1",
    "filename-regex": "^2.0.1",
    "for-own": "^1.0.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.1.11",
    "has-ansi": "^3.0.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "inherits": "^2.0.3",
    "is-binary-path": "^2.0.0",
    "is-buffer": "^2.0.2",
    "is-extendable": "^1.0.1",
    "is-extglob": "^2.1.1",
    "is-glob": "^4.0.0",
    "is-posix-bracket": "^0.1.1",
    "json5": "^1.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.21.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "object.omit": "^3.0.0",
    "os-tmpdir": "^1.0.2",
    "parse-glob": "^3.0.4",
    "path-is-absolute": "^1.0.1",
    "preserve": "^0.2.0",
    "randomatic": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "readdirp": "^2.1.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "regex-cache": "^0.4.4",
    "source-map": "^0.7.2",
    "strip-ansi": "^4.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "v8.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your package.json code

Comment: here above is my package.jscon file

Comment: can you at least improve the formatting of you `package.json` to be more legible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I can see `path-to-regexp` in your `package.json`, and that seem to be what heroku is complaining about. In your project directory, from your terminal, run:

```
npm install path-to-regexp --save
```

After then you can push to heroku again. This should solve your problem.

Comment: it is there in my package.json

Comment: what version is it? Can you please just post just the line where `path-to-regexp` is on your `package.json`

Comment: "path-to-regexp": "^2.2.0",

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure that is really present in the `package.json` you posted in your question. Check the `package.json` you posted again.

Comment: ya it is not there but later I installed it.